# Add dynamically an input js in a cell of table

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, input, addition

I'm trying to code a function where you can insert as many new input fields as the user want in JavaScript. Here is my code :

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript"> 
     function add() {       
        var element = document.createElement("input");      
        element.setAttribute("type", 'text');     
        element.setAttribute("value", 'text');     
        element.setAttribute("name", 'text');        
        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");      
        foo.appendChild(element);   
    } 
</SCRIPT>
```

Html Part

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="answer" autofocus="autofocus" ONBLUR="if(this.value!=''){this.form.submit()};" placeholder="Modify answer"/>
  <span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>   
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>   
</form>
```

This is working well, but not if I put it in this html structure :

```
 <table>
     <tr><td><form> <!--my html part -include the second form--> </form></td></tr>
 </table>
```

I don't really know why, as I'm not expert in js.. Is that because I'm in a `td` tag or because one `form` is inside the other.

If anyone can help or have another solution to achieve what I want, would be really greatful
Cheers

Comment: You can not have a form inside another form.

Comment: That is what I thought. Do you have anyalternate way to obtain the same result?

Comment: What result? If you want to append input fields to an existing form, just do so.

Comment: The input field must be created only if the user clicks on add button, and it must be created inside that first form (so that I can get back what he responds in the field)

Comment: Please describe the specific _problem_ you are having with this, instead of just telling us your “wish list”.

Comment: If you look at my code, everytime the user press add button, a new input textbox is created. That is working. But I have to create this box into a cell table that is part of a form (it already has one input field, and the user should be able to add another one). And that is where my pb is, cause it does no longer work

Comment: Well then append the created input element in the right place.

Comment: And put the form containing the add button elsewhere?

Comment: I wish not cause I don't really know how to put the created input somewhere else in js (Im no expert at all but Ill lokk for it) but otherwise, there one form into another : the main issue that I have from the start